# On angular 5 , how can i put the paging menu in the top section of the kendo grid?

Tags: html, kendo-grid, angular5, kendo-ui-angular2

[this the section i want to put on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pF9f.png)

i tried to read on the kendo website how to do it and i cant find anything, i know how to add and remove things from the pager menu, but cant find how to put it on top. 
this is the setup i have got so far:

```
<kendo-grid
[data]="gridData"
[pageSize]="gridState.take"
[skip]="gridState.skip"
[pageable]="{
  info: true,
  type: 'input',
  pageSizes: true,
  previousNext: true
}"
[selectable]="true"
[sort]="gridState.sort"
[sortable]="true"
(dataStateChange)="gridStateChange($event)"
(edit)="editHandler($event)"
(add)="addHandler($event)"
></kendo-grid>
```

i hope its OK to ask here this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KendoGrid uses [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for layout, so best option would be to use [css order property](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-9).

```
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [`
    .k-grid-aria-root{
      order: 20
    }
  `]
```

Here is also [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/THaXUyJ660uZqfzwtCwK?p=preview). If you want to avoid `ViewEncapsulation.None` you can also use `/deep/`:

```
  styles: [`
    /deep/.k-grid-aria-root{
      order: 20
    }
  `]
```